# How can I concatenate array elements into a string?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have string whose value are like FirstName;LastName;Phone e.g.

```
Tom;Hanks;12346789
```

I am populating a UIVewTable Label text is suposed to be FirstName,LastName e.g.

```
Tom,Hanks
```

Then I put the phone in details bit.

I am splitting the String based on semiColumn `;` then concatenating the first two elements of array and comma and third element in description.
It is working fine but I think the concatenation of array elements is not probably the best or normal way seems like a hack. Can I please get somehelp getting it right. My code is below

```
NSArray *title = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
//This bit below does not look right.
cell.textLabel.text =  [[[title objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@","] stringByAppendingString:[title objectAtIndex:1]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [title objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly better solution:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", [title objectAtIndex:0], [title objectAtIndex:1]];
```